# need help with Preg_replace Regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

these word1 and word2 is in brackets

want to remove the whole line depends on word2

```
[word1] something-line-text [word2] some text again
```

---

want to replace some text with another depends on word2

```
[word1] something-line-text [word2] some text again

into

REPLCACEDTEXT something-line-text some text again
```

---

```
some line text (something/something)

into

(something/something) some line text
```

Comment: So you want to remove word1 and word2?  And do you want to move anything in parens to the beginning of the line?

Comment: actually is middle of line and i want these replacements

Comment: So again, you want word1 and word2 always removed?  Or only if both are on the line?  Can you give a specific example of each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but this will look for [word1] and [word2] and remove them only if both are on the line:

```
$line = preg_replace('/word1(.*)word2/', '$1', $line);
```

This method could match on partial words, and you could be left with extra whitespace.  Slightly better would be:

```
$line = preg_replace('/\s?word1\b(.*)\s?word2\b/', '$1', $line);
```

This makes sure that they are matched as whole words using word boundaries and spaces.  I use spaces on one side so that the extra space is consumed.  If you don't care about that just use `\b` on both sides of each word.

Second case, moves the first parenthesized phrase to the beginning of the line:

```
$line = preg_replace('/(.*)(\(.*?\))/', '$2 $1', $line);
```

**Edit:**

After seeing your example, I think you want:

```
$line = preg_replace('/^\[Scene\].*/', '', $line);

$line = preg_replace('/\[\.*?\]\s+(.*)(\[.*?\])/', '$2 $1');

$line = preg_replace('/(.*)\s+(\(.*?\))/', '$2 $1');
```

Comment: thanks first one works correctly but output is like-- [] sometext [] -- i want to remove the last bracket too, or both ones ,like -- [] somtextonly---

Comment: Then include your brackets in the expression.  `$line = preg_replace('/\s?\[word1\](.*)\s?\[word2\]/', '$1', $line);`

Comment: hmm its not working, what is there's ---[hey you] sometext [you]----

Comment: hey its just working for first match only, what about other ones and its output remover first bracket not last one

Comment: You lost me.  If your text has spaces you have to use `\s`:  `\[hey\syou\]`.  I am not understanding your other question.  Can you post an *actual* example, and what it returns?

Comment: acttually this is working with first match only, second matches remains same

Comment: You have multiple matches on the same line?  Or are you running this on a multi-line string?

Comment: there are lots of lines to same matches , multi lines

Comment: If all of the lines are in the variable, you want: `$lines = preg_replace('/\s?\[word1\]([^\n\r]*)\s?\[word2\]/s', '$1', $lines);`

Comment: acctually its array and that one is also working on first match, and output is like ,$-- sometexttsdsds [word2] --- word1 is removed and word2 is still there

Comment: Did you make sure to escape your brackets? `\[` Can you post what you are currently using for your preg_replace?

Comment: what will be the regex for this 06:55:59-<kkksks>